# Understanding operator precedence in Tourlakis's Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In *Mathematical Logic by George Tourlakis* p. 15, priority of operators is explained in this terms:

[image]

[image]

So, two questions:

- What's the meaning of an operator "gluing first" ?
- What's the meaning of "all connectives are right associative" ?

Comment: Right associative means that $abC$ is interpreted as $a(bC)$, where $a$ and $b$ are 'connectives'. What is said in the previous sentence.

Comment: Gluing first is referring to $XaYbC$, for connectives $a$ and $b$, is interpreted as $Xa(YbC)$ if $b$ has higher priority than $a$, or as $(XaY)bC$ if $a$ has higher priority than $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the meaning of an operator "gluing first" ?

$P\circ Q * R$

$\circ$ gluing first

$$(P\circ Q) * R$$

$*$ gluing first

$$P\circ (Q * R)$$

> What's the meaning of "all connectives are right associative" ?

**associative** (meaning the operations can be grouped arbitrarily):
$$P\circ (Q \circ R)=(P\circ Q) \circ R$$
**left-associative** (meaning the operations are grouped from the left)
$$(P\circ Q) \circ R$$
**right-associative** (meaning the operations are grouped from the right)
$$P\circ (Q \circ R)$$
**non-associative** (meaning operations cannot be chained, often because the output type is incompatible with the input types)
$$P\circ (Q \circ R)\neq(P\circ Q) \circ R$$

See also [Operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)